# Why is int being passed as Object?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, java-7

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Stack {
    private ArrayList stack;
    private int pos;

    Stack() {
        stack = new ArrayList();
        pos = -1;
    }
    int pop() {
        if(pos < 0) {
             System.out.println("Stack underflow.");
             return 0;
        }
        int out = stack.get(pos);
        stack.remove(pos);
        pos--;
        return out;
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a basic variable length stack and this is a snippet of my code. When I run this, I get an error:

```
Main.java:16: error: incompatible types
   int out = stack.get(pos);
                       ^
required: int
found:    Object
```

Why is this being passed as an object?

Comment: `stack.get()` returns an `Object` since `stack` is an `ArrayList`. This is incompatible with the type of `out`. The `^` indicating where the error occurred is a red herring.

Comment: @NullUserException The error is correct, the `^` character position is just a bit wonky. It's referring to the return type, not the type in `pos`, and I admit that it's a bit hard to "point to" the return type with `^`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are not defining generic types held in your `ArrayList` called `stack` so you will get a raw `Object` return type from `ArrayList.get`:

You need to replace

```
ArrayList stack;
```

with

```
ArrayList<Integer> stack;
```

and similarly

```
stack = new ArrayList();
```

with

```
stack = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // new ArrayList<>(); for Java 7
```

Also have a look at using `java.util.Stack`

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I was only writing this as a way of teaching myself Java, otherwise I would have used the built-in.

Answer (score 1):

`stack` wasn't informed of what variable type it holds so it resorts to the generic `Object`.

```
ArrayList stack;
```

should be

```
ArrayList<Integer> stack;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `stack.get(int)` method returns an object. The int here is just the index. If you want to get the value of your stack at index `int` and it returns an `Integer` you need to do this:

`Integer x = stack.get([int index position]);`